# Can I use multiple event loops in a program where I also use multiprocessing module

Tags: multiprocessing, python-asyncio, event-loop

Thanks for any reply in advance.

I have the entrance program `main.py`:

```py
import asyncio
from loguru import logger
from multiprocessing import Process
from app.events import type_a_tasks, type_b_tasks, type_c_tasks


def run_task(task):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(task())
    loop.run_forever()


def main():
    processes = list()
    processes.append(Process(target=run_task, args=(type_a_tasks,)))
    processes.append(Process(target=run_task, args=(type_b_tasks,)))
    processes.append(Process(target=run_task, args=(type_c_tasks,)))

    for process in processes:
        process.start()
        logger.info(f"Started process id={process.pid}, name={process.name}")

    for process in processes:
        process.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

where the different types of tasks are similarly defined, for example `type_a_tasks` are:

```py
import asyncio
from . import business_1, business_2, business_3, business_4, business_5, business_6


async def type_a_tasks():
    tasks = list()
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(business_1.main()))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(business_2.main()))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(business_3.main()))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(business_4.main()))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(business_5.main()))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(business_6.main()))

    await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    return tasks
```

where the `main()` function of businesses(1-6) are `Future` objects provided by `asyncio`, in which I implemented my business code.

**Is my usage of multiprocessing and asyncio event loops above the correct way of doing it?**

I am doing so because I have a lot of asynchronous tasks to perform, but it doesn't seem appropriate to put them all in one event loop, so I divided them into three parts(a, b and c) accordingly, and I hope they can be run in three different processes to exert the capability of multiple CPU cores, in the meantime taking advantage of asyncio features.

I tried running my code, where the log records show there actually are different processes but all are using the same thread/event loop(knowing this by adding process_id and thread_id to loguru format)

Comment: "the log records show there actually are different processes but all are using the same thread/event loop(knowing this by adding process_id and thread_id to loguru format)".  That can't be true.  You are misinterpreting the log file.  A thread runs within a Process.  An event loop runs in a thread.  Saying that you have the same thread in two Processes is like saying that you found the same branch growing on two different trees.

Comment: @PaulCornelius I suspect if the problem lies in the way that I organize my code. The `logger` object which generated these log records is actually initialized right after the import of businesses(1-6) because it was put at the top of each business module, but outside of any class or function definition, however, `logger.info` was called inside so-called definitions.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Sorry to bother you, but putting aside how I organize my code, I want to know whether this actually can happen. Anyway, it occurred in my case where two log records have the same `thread_id` but different `process_id`s.

Answer (score 0):

this seens ok. Just use `asyncio.run(task())` inside `run_task` - it is simpler and there is no need to call `run_forever` (also, with the run_forever` call, your processes will never join the base one.

IDs for other objects across process may repeat - if you want, add to your logging the result of calling `os.getpid()` in the body of `run_task`.

(if these are, by chance, the same, that means that somehow subprocessing is using a "dummy" backend due to some configuration in your project - should not happen anyway)